# XQuery : most efficient way of for-iterating only when needed?

Tags: xml, for-loop, xquery, exist-db

Here is my example: if I have for example a very large XML file with 500.000 entries, like this:

```
<entries>
  <entry id="1">...</entry>
  <entry id="2">...</entry>
  <entry id="3">...</entry>
  ...
  <entry id="500000">...</entry>
</entries>
```

But I only want to keep entries whose ids are between, for example let's say 500 and 1000. Of course I would do :

```
let $entries := //entry[(xs:integer(./@id) >= 500) and (xs:integer(./@id) <= 1000)]
```

But I guess with this request I'm going to keep seeking after the entry #1000 through the 500.000 ones. Is it a way to stop seeking when I reach this entry #1000 ?

Comment: You really should say which XQuery engine you use. Some might have optimizations for that, others not... And almost all will iterate over all entires anyways, when creating the DOM.

Comment: It is eXist, in fact I was wondering if there is something like `break;` in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you noted in the comment that you're using eXist-db, let me provide some eXist-db specific guidance:

1. The subsequence() function will perform better than greater-than/less-than method.  For a discussion on this, see this Wolfgang Meier's post on this on the eXist-db mailing list, with the subject "Optimizing positional predicates for fast paging": http://markmail.org/message/aoe5wmy2gmf3aaqh.  So in your case:

   ```
   let $entries := subsequence(//entry, 500, 500)
   ```

   This will get you entries 500-1000.
2. If you do need to do comparison queries (greater-than/less-than), you may want to add a range index on @id.  For more on range indexes and how to set them up, see the eXist-db documentation page on range indexes: http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/indexing.xml#rangeidx.

Please feel free to join the eXist-db mailing list; we're always happy to discuss ways to optimize query performance.  Join at https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/exist-open, or search the archives at http://exist.markmail.org/.

Answer (score 1):

**In case the `entry` elements appear sorted by their `id` attribute (as in the provided document), most XPath (and XQuery) implementations should evaluate this efficiently**:

```
/*/entry[position() le 1000 and position() ge 500]
```